# Maven assembly filtering not working as I'd expect

Tags: java, maven

I am having a little issue with maven filtering. I wish to have it such that when it is unpacking and filtering a `dependencySet` it uses the pom.xml properties of the project that is being packaged rather that the project the files are included from.

So lets say I have this:

```
<dependencySet>
    <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    <includes>
        <include>group:artefact</include>
    </includes>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <outputFileNameMapping></outputFileNameMapping>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
    <unpackOptions>
        <includes>
            <include>start.py</include>
        </includes>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </unpackOptions>
</dependencySet>
```

The `start.py` has some tokens in it to filter (replace)...eg: `${project.artifactId}`, but rather than replacing it with the artifact id that maven is actually building (mvn package) it is using the id of the artifact that `start.py` resides in i.e`group:artefact`.

How do I get it to use the properties from the pom of the project being packaged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I can see, if the property exists in the parent pom (ie the pom of `group:artefact`) it will use that property, otherwise it will use the property in the pom of the project being built.